# Active job error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activejob

I try to run some work in background with Rails 4.2.6 and I got this error:

```
uninitialized constant Delayed::Job    
app/controllers/pipls_controller.rb:9:in `research'
```

Here is the code:

`app/jobs/miner.rb`

```
class Miner < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(params)
    ...
  end
end
```

`app/controllers/pipls_controller.rb`

```
class PiplsController < ApplicationController
  def research
    Miner.perform_later(params)
    redirect_to pipls_path
  end
end
```

`config/application.rb`

```
module Db
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
  end
end
```

`Gemfile`

```
gem 'delayed_job'
```

Sidekiq and Resque do not work either.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Did you add delayed_job (or sidekiq) to your Gemfile, ran `bundle`, and restarted the rails app?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I did it now, the error changed a bit, but still doesn't work

Comment: Did you config your application to use dj as a job processor?: `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job`